# Project Euler #3 in Python

Tags: python, math, primes

For reference:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>   What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

So I solved Project Euler's third problem after a fair bit of tinkering. Not the sleekest of codes, but it mostly works.

```
import math
import itertools

def is_prime(x):
    # Checks if the factor is prime. If not, breaks and looks at the next one
    split_tuple = math.modf(math.sqrt(x))
    max_prime_div_possible = int(split_tuple[1])
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, max_prime_div_possible+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            prime = False
            break
        else:
            pass
    return prime

def factor_me(x):
    # Creates a list of all factors of a number
    factors = []
    split_tuple = math.modf(math.sqrt(x))
    max_pf_possible = int(split_tuple[1])
    for i in xrange(2, max_pf_possible+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            x = x/i
        else:
            pass

    # Checks each factor for prime-ity, and if it is, sets it as the max prime factor.
    for j in factors:
        if is_prime(j) == True:
            max_prime_factor = j
        else:
            pass
    return max_prime_factor


print factor_me(600851475143) # works correctly
print factor_me(6008514751435) # fails
```

The thing is, even though the code works correctly with both the example test and proposed problem, if another digit is added to the number to be factorized, the code breaks. To give an example to make myself clear, take 6008514751435.
According to Wolfram Alpha, this factors into 5, 7 and 171671850041. However, according to my code, the largest factor is 7. So, well, I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only checking for factors up to the square root of the original number (6008514751435) which is 2451227.  Since the final factor is larger than this (171671850041), it is never added to `factors`.  Whatever is remaining in `x` when the loop exhausts, if it is not `1`, is the final factor.  You can also stop checking once `x` equals `1`.

```
for i in xrange(2, max_pf_possible+1):
    if x % i == 0:
        factors.append(i)
        x = x/i
        if x == 1: break # Check that all factors found.
else:
    factors.append(x)
```

If you are not familar with `for/else`, the `else` only executes if the `for` loop exhausts.  `break` from the loop will skip the `else`.

Comment: Crap, no: The code there is my solution to the #3 problem. But what I meant is, even when setting n to 6008514751435, the code spits out a 7.
Let me change that quickly for clarity.  
EDIT: Changed.

Comment: @matacusa, I mistyped as well.  I wrote `600851475143` instead of `6008514751435`, but the square root and reason for failure are still correct.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand now. However, if the maximum prime factor can be higher than the square root of the number, is the only choice to brute-force it? I imagine for such a large number that'd take a long, long time.

Comment: @matacusa, you can further optimize by only checking up to the square root of the current value of `x`, not the original value of `x`, but you also need to do a complete prime factor of the number.  If 2 goes into the number, keep checking that more 2s can go into the number until it can't, then move onto 3, etc.  Then only prime numbers will be in the final factors list.

Comment: I... don't quite get that. But I'll take a crack at it, nonetheless. Will make it work one way or the other. Thank you!

Comment: @matacusa, Try to factor `n=2*2*2*3*3*3`.  `factors` will be `[2,3,4,9]` with your current algorithm.  Change the `if x%i==0` to `while x%i==0` and the result will be `[2,2,2,3,3,3]`...all primes.

Comment: Ah, got it! Goddamnit, it was actually quite simple, but I wouldn't have been able to figure that out by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarkTolonen if you know that the code in the answer is incorrect -- in two ways, -- and you know the right way to write it, why don't you edit the two corrections in??